# Strange ddms log output with Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

I have 2 devices. The first one is Asus Eee Pad transformer with Android 4.1 onboard. When I connect it and debug using ddms log (in Eclipse) everything is OK: warnings are yellow, errors are red and so on. Also filters work fine.

But when I connect the new Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.1 onboard logcat shows me some strange unformatted output. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It seems that ddms treats all messages as warnings. I've updated all my development tools to the latest versions. It seems to be an OS bug.

Comment: I think this *could* be a side effect of the custom rom(there is no official S3 JB update out, isn't there?)

Comment: @Ahmad Yep, as far as I know the rom is custom.

Comment: try pulling the logcat straight trough the adb with `adb logcat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me in my Nexus. No custom stuff. No roms.
It got solved when I updated Eclipse to Juno.
Eventually if you want to keep your Eclipse version or already have Juno, it could work by re-installing as well.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse- go to help->check for updates-> update everything (ddms and other stuff should apear unupdated)
that's it